# Можно ли понять куда копируются файлы?

Tags: c#, .net

Например, `FileSystemWatcher` ловит какое-то изменение в отслеживаемой директории.

Можно ли отличить удаление файлов от перемещения, а так же во втором случае узнать куда перемещаются файлы?

Comment: [пробовал пример с msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: нет, но вопрос, немного в другом. Ведь если кто-то из вне будет перемещать файлы из одного места в другое, то они по идее будут считаться удаленными. Так же возникает вопрос, а можно ли понять куда перемещаются файлы?

Comment: Так ты попробуй. Кстати говоря, нет события перемещения

Comment: Смотря что считать перемещением. А если файл перемещается на другой диск? А если на сетевой? А если на FTP-сервер? А если в архив?

Comment: Все описанные вами случаи считаем за перемещение.

Comment: В приведённом примере сообщения удаления все приходят в onChange - вы пробовали создавать отдельный функтор для удаления и там отслеживать это?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно отслеживать удаление и перемещение файлов *внутри* отслеживаемой директории, то вам нужна пара событий `OnDeleted`/`OnCreated`.

Если вам нужно отслеживать перемещений файлов *из* отслеживаемоей директории, то, увы, `FileSystemWatcher` это не поддерживает. Для него любое перемещение файла -- это удаление. И отличить его от реального удаления нельзя.

Быстрое гугление подсказывает, что можно использовать file system watcher (через WinAPI). Есть также коммерческая библиотека [CallbackFilter](https://www.eldos.com/cbflt/index.php#product), которая, видимо, все делает за вас.